# Problema con slider de varios items

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

tengo este slider responsive creado con mediaquery desde js, estoy mostrando 20 sections de varios colores que se mueven automaticamente de izquierda a derecha al empezar y viceversa al llegar al ultimo seccion, tengo un problema y es que al llegar al ultimo section, el slider se mueve en dos y no en uno, cosa que no sucede al llegar al primero. ¿Esto se debe a esto  `i = Math.floor(Math.min(Math.max(i, 0), number_sections - sections_to_show - 1));` ? resto -1 para que no me quede un espacio vacio al final del slider

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

  var i = 0;
  var slider_automatic = true;
  var right_arrow = $('#right-circle');
  var left_arrow = $('#left-circle');

    right_arrow.on('click', function(){
        i++;
        changeResize();
    });

    left_arrow.on('click', function(){
        i--;
        stop_slider();
        changeResize();
    });

  function stop_slider(){
    if(i == 0){
        slider.css('left', 0); // Si i es igual a 0 deja de moverse a la izquierda, 0 es el valor inicial, por lo que al llegar al primer section, dejará de moverse a la izquierda
    }
  }

  var slider = $('.slider');
  var sections = $('section');
  var number_sections = sections.length;
  
  // Media query 
  const tablet = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)');
  const small_tablet = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');
  const mobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
  const small_mobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 280px)');

  function changeResize() {
   
  var sections_to_show = 5;

  if (i > 0) {
    slider.css({
      'left': '-' + 20 * i + '%' // movemos slider cada vez que i es mayor que 0, el valor cambia dependiendo del media query, esta configuracion es para pantallas mayores a 1024px
  });    
}

    if(small_mobile.matches){
        sections_to_show = 1;

        if (i > 0) {
    slider.css({
      'left': '-' + 100 * i + '%' // configuracion para pantalla igual o menor a 280px
    });    
}
    }

    else if (mobile.matches) {
        sections_to_show = 2;

        if (i > 0) {
    slider.css({
      'left': '-' + 50 * i + '%' // configuracion para pantalla igual o menor a 600px
    });    
}
    }

    else if (small_tablet.matches) {
        sections_to_show = 3;

        if (i > 0) {
    slider.css({
      'left': '-' + 33.3333333333 * i + '%' // configuracion para pantalla igual o menor a 768px
    });    
}
    }

    else if (tablet.matches) {
        sections_to_show = 4;
        if (i > 0) {
    slider.css({
      'left': '-' + 25 * i + '%' // configuracion para pantalla igual o menor a 1024px
    });    
}
    }

  slider.css('width', 100 * number_sections / sections_to_show + '%'); // Define un ancho del slider, el ancho varia dependiendo de los sections a mostrar

  sections.css('width', 100 / number_sections * sections_to_show + '%'); // Define un ancho de cada section, el ancho varia dependiendo de los sections a mostrar

  i = Math.floor(Math.min(Math.max(i, 0), number_sections - sections_to_show - 1)); // var i le definimos un valor minimo (0) y un valor maximo que cambia dependiendo de los sections a mostrar

  if(i == number_sections - sections_to_show - 1){
    slider_automatic = false; // si i es igual al maximo valor cambia el sentido automatico del slider
  }
    }

  changeResize();

  window.addEventListener('resize', changeResize);

  setInterval(function(){
    if(slider_automatic == true){ // Activa slider automatico de izquierda a derecha //
    right_arrow.trigger('click'); 
    }
    else if(slider_automatic == false) { // Activa slider automatico de derecha a izquierda //
    left_arrow.trigger('click');
    }
},3000);

});
```

```css
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.container{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.slider{
display: flex;
position: relative;
transition: .4s linear;
left: 0;
}
section{
height: 300px;
}
#left-circle,
#right-circle{
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 30;
cursor: pointer;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
font-size: 48px;
}
#left-circle{
left: 0;
}
#right-circle{
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="container">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left" id="left-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right" id="right-circle"></i>
<div class="slider">
<section style="background: darkred;"></section>
<section style="background: darkblue;"></section>
<section style="background: darkorange;"></section>
<section style="background: black;"></section>
<section style="background: gold;"></section>
<section style="background: lightblue;"></section>
<section style="background: yellow;"></section>
<section style="background: brown;"></section>
<section style="background: skyblue;"></section>
<section style="background: green;"></section>
<section style="background: gray;"></section>
<section style="background: purple;"></section>
<section style="background: chocolate;"></section>
<section style="background: pink;"></section>
<section style="background: orange;"></section>
<section style="background: maroon;"></section>
<section style="background: violet;"></section>
<section style="background: navy"></section>
<section style="background: fuchsia"></section>
<section style="background: darkgray"></section>
</div>
    </div>
```

He comentado mi código para que les pueda ser más facil de leer, espero me puedan ayudar con este problema, igual seguire intentando sobre que hize mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depués de intentarlo varias veces, pude arreglar el problema, espero que este slider responsive les pueda ser util para algun proyecto:

```js
var i = 0;
  var slider_automatic = true;
  var right_arrow = $('#right-circle');
  var left_arrow = $('#left-circle');

    right_arrow.on('click', function(){
        i++;
        changeResize();
    });

    left_arrow.on('click', function(){
        i--;
        changeResize();
    });

  var slider = $('.slider');
  var sections = $('section');
  var number_sections = sections.length;

  const tablet = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)');
  const small_tablet = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');
  const mobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
  const small_mobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 280px)');

  function changeResize() {

    var sections_to_show = 5;

    if(small_mobile.matches){
        sections_to_show = 1;   
    }

    else if (mobile.matches) {
        sections_to_show = 2;       
    }

    else if (small_tablet.matches) {
        sections_to_show = 3;   
    }

    else if (tablet.matches) {
        sections_to_show = 4;   
    }

  slider.css('width', 100 * number_sections / sections_to_show + '%');
  sections.css('width', 100 / number_sections * sections_to_show + '%');

  i = Math.floor(Math.min(Math.max(i, 0), number_sections - sections_to_show));

  if (i > 0) {
    slider.css({
      'left': '-' + 100 / sections_to_show * i + '%'
  });    
}

  if(i == 0){
    slider.css('left', 0);
    slider_automatic = true; 
  } 

  if(i == number_sections - sections_to_show){
    slider_automatic = false;
  }
    }

  changeResize();

  window.addEventListener('resize', changeResize); 

  setInterval(function(){
    if(slider_automatic == true){ // Activa slider automatico de izquierda a derecha //
    right_arrow.trigger('click'); 
    }
    else if(slider_automatic == false) { // Activa slider automatico de derecha a izquierda //
    left_arrow.trigger('click');
    }
},3000);
```

```css
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.container{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.slider{
display: flex;
position: relative;
transition: .4s linear;
left: 0;
}
section{
height: 300px;
}
#left-circle,
#right-circle{
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 30;
cursor: pointer;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
font-size: 48px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#left-circle{
left: 0;
}
#right-circle{
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>


<div class="container">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left" id="left-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right" id="right-circle"></i>
<div class="slider">
<section style="background: darkred;"></section>
<section style="background: darkblue;"></section>
<section style="background: darkorange;"></section>
<section style="background: black;"></section>
<section style="background: gold;"></section>
<section style="background: lightblue;"></section>
<section style="background: yellow;"></section>
<section style="background: brown;"></section>
<section style="background: skyblue;"></section>
<section style="background: green;"></section>
<section style="background: gray;"></section>
<section style="background: purple;"></section>
<section style="background: chocolate;"></section>
<section style="background: pink;"></section>
<section style="background: orange;"></section>
<section style="background: maroon;"></section>
<section style="background: violet;"></section>
<section style="background: navy"></section>
<section style="background: fuchsia"></section>
<section style="background: darkgray"></section>
</div>
    </div>
```